# Aggregation on a window function with minimum windows size

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, window-functions

Assuming that I have a table that collects ordered records:

```sql
SELECT * FROM items_table ORDER BY day ASC
```

| day | total_items |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 6 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 |
| 6 | 2 |
| 7 | 4 |

I wish to calculate the maximum number of "total_items" for every 3 days, while the window is at least of size 3.
If at a specific row the window size is not big enough the returned value should be NULL.

| day | min_3_days_total_items |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL |
| 2 | NULL |
| 3 | 6 |
| 4 | 6 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 6 | 2 |
| 7 | 4 |

in Pandas it would be:

```py
df['total_items'].rolling(3, min_periods=3).max()
```

How can this be done in BigQuery SQL?

Answer (score 1):

```
case
  when count(*) over (order by day rows between 2 preceding and current row) = 3
  then max(total_items) over (order by day rows between 2 preceding and current row) end
```

You could similarly base your test on `row_number()` or `lag()` if the nulls are only because they appear at the beginning of the list. I guess that depends on how you want to think about the data. You can certainly alias your window if desired and if you favor `if` versus `case` then it's still equivalent.

I specifically assumed you don't have gaps in the day numbering. If those are important to consider you might look at whether using `range between` is more appropriate.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=96e4e60269535586501da5b9fa70e206

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach

```
select *,
  if(count(*) over recent_3_days = 3, 
    max(total_items) over recent_3_days, 
    null) as max_items_in_recent_min_3_days
from items_table  
window recent_3_days as (order by day range between 2 preceding and current row)
order by day
```